# Mongoose typescript match schema required fields with ts types

Tags: typescript, mongodb, visual-studio-code, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How can I make my type and my schema type checking on required / optional?

Is this vscode related ?

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

type User = {
  username: string;
  email?: string;
  password: string | undefined;
};

const userSchema = new Schema<User>({
  username: { type: String },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});

export const UserModel = model<User>('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Mongoose's `InferSchemaType` to create types automatically based on your schema:

```
import { Schema, InferSchemaType } from 'mongoose';

const schema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});

type User = InferSchemaType<typeof schema>;

const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

You can find more info [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/schemas.html), under the "**Automatic type inference**".

Comment: I know about InferSchemaType but unfortunately the caveats mentioned in the article are conditions we can't afford in our project this will require to many changes